# Could not split the String created from char array using \n

Tags: java, arrays, saxparser, stringtokenizer, split

I could not split the String created from `char array` using `\n`. Even after converted from `char`s to `String`, `split()` or `stringtokenizer()` could not split the string having `\n`. Your help is much appreciated.

```
char[] c = new char[]{'H', 'i', '\\', 'n', 'H', 'i'};  //format I get from saxparser

String val = new String(c);

System.out.println("val: "+val); //val: Hi\nHi

System.out.println("isContain: "+val.contains("\n"));  //false
System.out.println("isContain: "+val.contains("\\n")); //true

System.out.println("splitted size: "+val.split("\n").length); //1
System.out.println("splitted size: "+val.split("\\n").length); //1
```

Comment: it should be `\\\\n`

Comment: have you tried this `val.split("\\\\n").length`, since `split` uses regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the last line to contain the below code

```
System.out.println("splitted size: " + val.split("\\\\n").length); // 2
```

Since split uses regex passing '\n' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

use ////n;

```
char[] c = new char[]{'H', 'i', '\\', 'n', 'H', 'i'};  //format I get from saxparser

    String val = new String(c);

    System.out.println("val: "+val); //val: Hi\nHi

    System.out.println("isContain: "+val.contains("\n"));  //false
    System.out.println("isContain: "+val.contains("\\n")); //true

    System.out.println("splitted size: "+val.split("\n").length); //1
    System.out.println("splitted size: "+val.split("\\\\n").length);//2
```